# Azure Pipelines: Fail to use DotNetCoreCLI custom command

Tags: azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I struggle to allow for debugging my own nuget packages hosted on azure.
I tried quite a few things since this is apparently a common problem with many ways to address.
Classic pipeline like this worked (yaml view):

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Create NuGet Packages'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj;!**/*.Tests.csproj'
    packDirectory: Solution/Packages
    nobuild: true
    includesymbols: true
    includesource: true
```

but at the end debugging still would not work.
Then I came across this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg
But now I keep failing running my .net cli custom command.
I simply don't know how to specify my project(s) to be packed as arguments.
Anything I tried failed:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'dotnet pack **/*.csproj;!**/*.Tests.csproj -p:IncludeSymbols=true -p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg'
```

I tried a few paths without wildcards but the problem is I do not even know which (relative) path to use. I tried quite a few paths but none worked.
How do I pass arguments like project paths?

Update:
The errors I get vary depending on the approach but either the command can not be parsed or it says the project was not found.

Comment: What error do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task has a redundant `dotnet` in its custom command.

Try

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'pack **/*.csproj;!**/*.Tests.csproj -p:IncludeSymbols=true -p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg'
```